# Media queries give a headache

Tags: html, css, media-queries

My main smartphone is a Galaxy S8 Plus.

The media queries for this device are:

```
@media only screen and (min-width: 360px) and (orientation: portrait)
```

Let's start with the portrait orientation. This one, I'm understanding 100%, but here comes the problem.
This is the media query for landscape:

```
@media only screen and (min-width: 740px) and (orientation: landscape)
```

Everytime I code in this media query it applies to my desktop which has a 1920 * 1200 resolution. I know it's influenced by the `min-width: 740px`.

Now, my question is are:

- How do I tackle this problem?
- Can I create a single query that covers both portrait and landscape?
- If so , what are the best practices for units in responsive web design? Right now I'm using vh and vw in my project, but I think it creates a mess sometimes.
- And one last question: how do I cover most devices out there with a minimal use of queries?

Comment: Instead of orientation, you can try with `height` property in your media query i think.

Comment: Also for your other questions i say combine common properties which applies with specific range with `min` or `max` media query and rest within range combines so it won't be applied to all starting or ending point of size.

Comment: Get rid of orientation and target by width. For media queries, you always have to make sure you cover all your width. In your case, your media query stopped at 740, you need to make at least one more to cover the next range (desktops most likely). Even when you go from big to small, you still need to cover all ranges

Comment: Thanks a lot for taking your time. 
I managed to fix it by myself in the end .. haha
Although your fix with the gives `transform: translateX(0px)` me a weird transition when it starts, but using `transform: none` fixes that. Don't know what is happening there. Inca o data, apreciez ajutorul oferit!

Answer (score 0):

Good CSS is minimal. Test my approach:

1. Global styles on top. For example font colors, font weights, backgrounds etc.
2. Then, use media queries:

@media screen and (max-width:1200px){

}

@media screen and (max-width:992px){

}

@media screen and (max-width:640px){

}

and so on... Higher widths are on top. In "mobile-first" approach, use min-width, and then lower widths are on top.

3. Try to avoid orientation property. Use this property only when you really need it.
4. vw and vh are convenient but remember that they are not supported on older browsers.
5. Bootstrap is good framework but you should learn how to make logic CSS from the scratch first. Keep up the good work.

Comment: Thanks mate!
I'll try your suggestions
That's why I'm asking, because I don't want to use any frameworks.

Comment: Yes, frameworks (in most cases, especially in small projects) are 95% of website code when you use only 5 to 10% of its functionality :)

Answer (score -1):

1. To deal with the problem that it applies to desktop change `min` to `max`, there is a "standard" for what the media queries should be seen [here](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/layout/grid/#grid-options), your media query described the medium size of < `768px` for horizontal and very small size of < `576px`
2. You don't need to include the orientation, you can simply write `@media only screen and (min-width: 740px)` then you apply for both, but you should have two media queries to make sure you cover both
3. `vh` and `vw` work best for creating responsive design, however if you are coding for IE then it might a problem, and you will need to find an alternativ to calculating height
4. Use Boostrap, it does everything for you almost